# NetBeans, Jacoco and Optional.orElseThrow()

Tags: java, netbeans, jacoco

I use NetBeans and JaCoCo, configured thus in my project's Maven POM:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
        <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.7.201606060606</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>report</id>
                <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>report</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

For this code:

```
public String showName(Optional<String> maybeName) {
    return maybeName.orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("Missing name"));
}
```

And **only** this test:

```
@Test
public void testShowName() {
    String actual = foo.showName(Optional.of("John"));
    assertEquals("John", actual);
}
```

... then NetBeans code coverage report shows 100% coverage. This is not correct, since I have not exercised the case where `maybeName == Optional.empty()` and the exception is thrown.

Using EclEmma in Eclipse, I see partial coverage, as expected.

Is there some further configuration I need to give JaCoCo?

Answer (score 1):

JaCoCo only has awareness of instructions and branches in your classes, and it does not have awareness of instructions and branches in libraries.  All the instructions in your class were executed, including the instructions in the lambda expression, and your code does not have any branches of it own, only implicit branches in the Optional.orElseThrow method.

If this feature is of interest to you, I suggested asking on the [JaCoCo user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jacoco) whether the project is interested in this feature before you [open a feature request issue](https://github.com/jacoco/jacoco).  Perhaps it would be possible to add configuration to specify a set of classes/methods that should generate a synthetic branch.